# Unexpected mongo exit code 100 meteor, can't start mongo server

Tags: meteor

On windows 10 with meteor 1.2.1,

```
=> Started proxy.
Unexpected mongo exit code 100. Restarting.
Unexpected mongo exit code 100. Restarting.
Unexpected mongo exit code 100. Restarting.
Can't start Mongo server.
MongoDB had an unspecified unchaougt exception.
This can be caused by MongoDb being unable to write to a local database. Check that you have permissions to write to .meteor/local. MongoDb does not support filesystems like NFs that do not allow file locking.
PS C:\Users\54N1\Desktop\åäö\app
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution: remove none standard characters from directory name!**

This error seems to be frequent, but one of the reasons it can be caused is due to using none standard characters in the directory path in this case ÅÄÖ, the issue is resolved by renaming folder to AAA.

Comment: Thanks! I had the same problem on Windows. There were some cyrillic characters in path to my project. I've created a symlink to that folder, and didn't use cyrillic in path to symlink. That helped: from that symlink meteor starts ok! Thanks!